# replace a string of n chars with a random string of n chars for each line in bash

Tags: bash, random, replace

I have a file called tmp.txt. It has chars 'a-z' separated by spaces on one side of a tab delimited file and numbers '0-9.' on the other side. for each line I want to do some random replaces of 1-3 characters.  my tmp.txt looks like this:

```
s h e h a d y o u r 0.9472 0.2074 0.4878 0.2227 0.4998 0.2841 0.5323 0.4254 0.539 0.4981  
d o n t a s k m e t o c a r r y 0.9741 0.0999 0.338 0.0572 0.4514 0.223 0.5036 0.3835 0.4844 0.6306 
e v e n t h e n 0.8549 0.1265 0.5248 0.2713 0.622 0.2011 0.4334 0.4137 0.4788 0.5435
```

I have written this much of a script so far:

```
cat tmp.txt | while IFS= read -r line; 
    do 
        for i in {1..3}; 
        do 
            a=$(tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | head -c $i);
            b=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | head -c $i);
            sed -i 's/$a/$b/g';
        done; 
    done
```

The sed doesn't seem to be finding $line since I get:

```
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
```

I thought that I was still within read -r line in this loop but it seems I am wrong. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of sed do you use?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Well you haven’t supplied any input file to `sed`, how can you supply any option to sed.

Comment: @Mihir the input should be line

Comment: @Cyrus I tried to change the quotes with no luck. Thank you anyway.  The version is sed (GNU sed) 4.4

Comment: `sed -i` replaces the **file** it gets on the command line. You aren't passing it a filename at all, so how would it do anything? (How's it supposed to get `$line` anyhow?)

Comment: BTW, if you wanted to feed `line` to `sed`, and reassign the variable based on its output, `line=$(sed -e "s/$a/$b/g" <<<"$line")` would do that. However, it's not an approach I at all recommend, for the reasons described in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use `sed` for this at all.** Especially, don't run it three separate times for each line of input: Command substitutions are slow, and external command invocation is even slower.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*|4.0*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.1+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

# Open a continuous stream of acceptable random characters
exec {random_chars_fd}< <(tr -dc 'a-z0-9' </dev/urandom)

while IFS= read -r line; do
  for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do

    # filter for alpha and numeric characters in our input line
    possible_chars=${line//[![:alnum:]]}

    # pick a random position in the filtered string, and take the character it contains
    char_to_replace=${possible_chars:$(( RANDOM % ${#possible_chars} )):1}

    # now, read one character from our stream of random inputs
    read -n 1 replacement <&$random_chars_fd

    # and replace all instances of the randomly-selected character in our input with the
    # randomly-selected output character.
    line=${line//"$char_to_replace"/"$replacement"}
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$line" # print our new version of the line
done <tmp.txt
```

Some changes of note:

- Nowhere at all in this code do we use command substitutions (`$(...)`, or their legacy backtick-syntax equivalent). Spinning up external commands incurs substantial overhead, so internal bash operations should be used instead wherever possible; when we *do* run an external command, we run only one copy and keep it going for the whole script, instead of starting new instances over and over in a loop.
- All the string-splicing operations are done with [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) syntax, also discussed in [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) -- native, internal-to-bash operations which can perform replacement operations, pick out individual characters from a string, etc.
- We aren't piping from `cat` into our loop, but instead redirecting. This avoids serious bugs, as discussed in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), and is also somewhat more efficient.

Comment: I get a Syntax error: redirection unexpected on line 5: exec {random_chars_fd}< <(tr -dc 'a-z0-9' </dev/urandom)

Comment: I have bash 4.4

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: You may *have* it, but if you get that error, you aren't *running the script with* it.

Comment: If you run `sh somescript`, or use a `#!/bin/sh` shebang? That's not bash.

Comment: BTW, catching that kind of situation is exactly why I started this answer with the `case $BASH_VERSION in` line.

Comment: Can you please show me this code eating tabs? That doesn't happen in the copy running online at https://ideone.com/g8RC1q

Comment: What edit? See the edit history at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57170961/revisions -- I didn't change the code at all, only the explanatory text (past r2, at least, and I wouldn't have expected r1 to work at all, which is why I deleted it to work on things in the background).